# Big theta of function with multiple types of n

Tags: big-o

I have the following function:

```html
    <html>
      <head>
       <script type="text/javascript" async  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML">
       </script>
      </head>
      <body>
        $$\frac{n*7^n+\frac{8}{n!}}{(n+7)*7^n}=\Theta(1)$$
      </body>
    </html>
```

I don't how they come to this. What is the proper way to analyse a function to theta notation?

Comment: Perhaps this question should be asked on https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: oke i will do that. thanks!

Comment: Maybe you could move it there completely and consider deleting this question as it's not likely to receive as much attention here anyway.